# Conditional formatting based off the previous X number of cells

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I am trying to setup conditional formatting so that the formatting takes effect if the previous 4 cells in a column are blank.  I need the range inside the conditional formatting formula to move as it is applied to cells below it, for example:

[image: Store Sales]

If I am tracking sales by store, if there is a 4 week period where a certain store doesn't record any sales I want those 4 weeks to automatically highlight.

My current formula is to select cells B5:B11, enter the formula =SUM(B2:B5)=0 to trigger the cell highlighting.

My problem is that when I look at cell B6 the range it looks for to be blank is still B2:B5 and I need it to be B3:B6.

Is there a way to set this up so that the range will change as it moves down a column?

Comment: How do you know it is looking at cells `B2:B5`? The conditional format you describe works just fine for me

Comment: When I select B6 and go into the conditional formatting page it shows that the range is still B2:B5

Comment: Excel is showing you the Formula for the entire range (you should see that in the same dialog box). I did a quick test with your sample data and formula and the following cells were coloured: `B9`, `C5`, `C6`, `D5`, `D9` and `D10`. Let us know if that is not the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

This one has gotten me thinking a bit, and here is my solution for it.

My solution needs to use four conditional formattings, i.e. set up four conditional formattings in each cell, and then use **format painter** to apply the conditional format to all the cells.

Suppose your week table is in range `A1:D20`, and suppose you want to highlight cells if there are **at least** (not only) four consecutive blank cells.

[image: Week Table]

Highlight cell `B2`, and then set up conditional formatting using the following four formulas:

```
=SUM(OFFSET($B2,0,0,4,1))=0

=SUM(OFFSET($B2,-1,0,4,1))=0

=SUM(OFFSET($B2,-2,0,4,1))=0

=SUM(OFFSET($B2,-3,0,4,1))=0
```

Then should have something similar to the following when examing the conditional formatting window:

[image: CF in Cell B2]

Lastly, highlight cell `B2`, use the `Format Painter` function under **Home** tab and then apply the format to the rest of the cells in the week table. Then you should have something similar to the following:

[image: CF Result]

It is easy to find the first blank cell of four consecutive blank cells, but it is difficult to identify the second, third and fourth blank cells using one formula. The workaround uses four different formulas to identify each of the four blank cells (I hope this makes sense). Please note the following is only looking at Column B of my example, not all columns:

[image: Logic]

Comment: Thanks for the solution, the only change I had to make was removing the absolute cell reference from B2 in all the equations so that it would copy over to the new columns using format painter.  Other than that it works great.

Answer (score 0):

Not pretty, but it works. This will highlight all occasions where the store has **at least** 4 weeks of consecutive donuts.

Columns B:D = Original Data

Columns E:G = Helper Set 1

Columns H:J = Helper Set 2

There's probably a way to get just one helper set, but this works and was easy to validate. First I added 3 empty rows above week 1.

In cells E4, E5 and E6 place a 0. You don't have to, you could also leave these blank.

**Cell E5 formula**, which is counting the number of consecutive blanks:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(B5),E4+1,0)
```

Drag it over to column G and drag it down.

**Cell H5 formula**, which is looking at 4 weeks later to see if there were consecutive blanks found in helper set 1:

```
=IF(E8>=4,"Yes","No")
```

Drag it over to column J and drag it down. Also, in the row above it, repeat week 1 values.

Lastly, select your original data range (B5:D14) and create this conditional formatting formula:

```
=(OR(H5="Yes",H4="Yes",H3="Yes",H2="Yes"))
```

[image]

Once you're satisfied, you can hide rows 2:4 and can also hide your helper columns.

Answer (score 0):

Apply the following condition to each respective ranges:

Range: `B2:D2`:

```
=SUM(B2:B5)=0
```

Range: `B3:D3`:

```
=OR(SUM(B2:B5)=0, SUM(B3:B6)=0)
```

Range: `B4:D4`:

```
=OR(SUM(B2:B5)=0, SUM(B3:B6)=0, SUM(B4:B7)=0)
```

Range: `B4:D8`:

```
=OR(SUM(B2:B5)=0, SUM(B3:B6)=0, SUM(B4:B7)=0, SUM(B5:B8)=0)
```

Result with sample data:

[image]